# Unknown profiler issue when using Typemock and CodeRush

Tags: unit-testing, coderush, typemock, typemock-isolator

I'm using VS 2017 and Typemock version 8.6.9. I've been working with CodeRush as a test runner for a while and it worked perfectly. Now I started using their coverage tool and got the following error:

```
*** Unknown profiler is enabled please contanct typemock@support.com with the flowing data: unknown profiler clsid = {B146457E-9AED-4624-B1E5-968D274416EC}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at Typemock - the unit testing company

It is a well-known issue, there was a problem in the integration of coverage profilers between latest Isolator and CodeRush Code Coverage.

You are welcome to update to the [latest version](https://www.typemock.com/download-isolator/) which includes all fixes.